# command line argument from java code to exe are not sent completely

Tags: java, command-line, exe

I am executing .exe program from Java program, sending string as command line argument. .exe program runs and print on console command line arguments which I read it in java through BufferedReader object. After reading it I found out that argument is not getting completely to exe. 
Here is the string I am sending.

```
 String script3 = "$tempDoc = '<QueryList><Query Id=\"0\" >';$selectNodes = $doc.SelectNodes('/QueryList/Query/Select');$invalidLog=\"\" \r\n" + 
        " foreach($s in $selectNodes)\r\n" + 
        "{$s=$s.Path -replace'\"';if($logs -contains $s){$tempDoc+='<Select Path=\"'+$s+'\">*</Select>';}else{if(!$invalidLog){$invalidLog = $s;}else {$invalidLog=$invalidLog +',' + $s;}}} $tempDoc += '</Query></QueryList>';$query = $tempDoc;$Results='<Error>EventLogNotFoundException:Unable to find '+$invalidLog+' event logs.</Error>';\r\n" + 
        "$slp = \"false\"}else {$Results= $tempResult};$flag=\\\"false\\\";}else{if($Results.count -eq 0){$Results +=$tempResult;}else {$tempResult.removeAt(0);$Results += $tempResult;}\r\n" + 
        "$startTime=$endTime;}}}}\r\n" + 
        "$Results+= '<EndofPoll>';\r\n" + 
        "$RunspacePool.Close() | Out-Null\r\n" + 
        " $RunspacePool.Dispose() | Out-Null \r\n" + 
        " $counter=$counter+1;$Results | Out-String;if($slp -eq \\\"true\\\"){sleep $SleepSeconds ; [Console]::Out.Flush();[System.GC]::Collect();invoke-command -scriptblock {[Console]::Out.Flush();[System.GC]::Collect()}}}}\"";
```

After reading from BufferedReader object I found it as

```
$tempDoc = '<QueryList><Query Id=0 >';$selectNodes = $doc.SelectNodes('/QueryList/Query/Select');$invalidLog=" 
 foreach($s in $selectNodes)
{$s=$s.Path -replace'';if($logs-contains
```

Is there anything I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you are spawning a process from a Java application which executes a `.exe` with a multi-line command line?

Comment: Why not store script in resource and read it insteed of such nasty concatenatuion?

Comment: How do you write or execute the script? What does the String look like when passed? Can you do a System.out before starting the script? [mcve]